Duplicate folder in VSCode file explorer
Please see the picture

Notice the backend folder is shown twice.
Hovering over it shows the same path, and opening it shows the same items, so it is indeed the same folder.
What's going on here? Why is the same folder shown more than once?
EDIT1:
(venv) noams@DESKTOP-34S5F1I:~/src/personal_website$ ll -a
total 120
drwxr-xr-x 9 noams noams  4096 Oct 19 13:44 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 noams noams  4096 Oct 18 14:36 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 noams noams   199 Oct 11 00:43 .aidigestignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 noams noams   201 Oct 19 16:16 .env
drwxr-xr-x 9 noams noams  4096 Oct 19 16:02 .git/
drwxr-xr-x 3 noams noams  4096 Oct 12 19:40 .github/
-rw-r--r-- 1 noams noams   716 Oct 12 19:40 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 2 noams noams  4096 Sep 20 19:29 .vscode/
drwxr-xr-x 2 noams noams  4096 Oct 11 00:43 ai_help/
drwxr-xr-x 9 noams noams  4096 Oct 19 15:51 backend/
-rw-r--r-- 1 noams noams   264 Oct 11 00:43 build.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 noams noams 60833 Oct 19 13:44 codebase.md
drwxr-xr-x 6 noams noams  4096 Oct 12 19:40 frontend/
-rw-r--r-- 1 noams noams   784 Oct 11 00:43 mock-db.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 noams noams   637 Oct 11 00:43 run_dev.sh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 noams noams     0 Oct  9 16:46 test_key.json
drwxr-xr-x 5 noams noams  4096 Sep 19 16:33 venv/

Edit2:
(venv) noams@DESKTOP-34S5F1I:~/src/personal_website$ ll -a ..
total 2248
drwxr-xr-x  8 noams noams    4096 Oct 18 14:36 ./
drwxr-x--- 13 noams noams    4096 Oct 19 16:21 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 noams noams    4096 Oct  1 12:14 backup/
drwxr-xr-x  2 noams noams    4096 Oct 18 14:36 cat_narration/
drwxr-xr-x  2 noams noams    4096 Sep 28 21:57 gcp/
-rw-r--r--  1 noams noams 2266947 Sep 19 13:35 get-pip.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 noams noams    4096 Sep 27 14:28 heroku/
drwxr-xr-x  9 noams noams    4096 Oct 19 13:44 personal_website/
drwxr-xr-x  2 noams noams    4096 Sep 28 15:18 prompt_engineering/


Some symbolic link? Show how the folder that contains personal_website looks if you do ls -a or alike command.

@Destroy666 edited

I wrote folder that contains, not is, personal_website.

@Destroy666 edited

Ok, so it's something in VSCode. Are you using any plugins related to file explorer?

@Destroy666 Not to my knowledge. Just Python and some basic javascript plugins. Not even sure how to list them, but I don't believe it's related. Maybe.
